# If we use multiple assertion first assertion is failed how should i continue my scripts?

Tags: python, unit-testing, automated-tests

If we have used multiple assertion first assertion is failed Ex. assert.Equal(Expected Text, actual Text) if both texts are not equal test will fail, without test fail how should i continue the next assertion in my script and finally test will show all errors. How could i make this?

Answer (score 2):

Multiple assertions per test are somewhat an anti-pattern - ideally, tests should be written such that they only assert on one aspect. This allows the test suite to have sufficient granularity that a failing test can identify any issue precisely.

If you're asserting on a range of cases it can often be achieved with parametrization (e.g. `pytest.mark.parametrize`), which allows data-driven testing. This takes the repetition out of the test code, by generating multiple tests from one.

Asserting on different stages of a test might be a sign that the test is testing too many things at once, in this case I suggest to try to split the asserts into separate tests, each with descriptive names. However, if you really want to test steps of a longer process with accumulating failures (and it's possible/safe to do so), there is limited support for this in the plugin [pytest-check](https://github.com/okken/pytest-check).